# git log shows only the most recent revision of a file

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

In order to compare two revisions of a file in a project, I did a `git log /path/to/file` which only returns the last commit.

When executing `git blame /path/to/file` I got the trace of each line with the correct sha, dates, and authors.

So the commits are stored but somehow `git log` doesn't show them.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Was this file ever renamed/moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file was probably renamed copied in its last commit. Try `git log --follow -- path/to/file`

Comment: That was it! Indeed the file was moved in the hierarchy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Btw this works for me even without the `--` in front of `path/to/file`

Comment: @janos: yeah, it works without, but writing the `--` helps resolve ambiguities with files and branches with the same name.